# Proof on why $0-1+2-3+4-\ldots\neq-1/4$

Tags: proof-verification, power-series, uniform-convergence, divergent-series

When reviewing my notes on series' convergence, I thought of applying a workaround on why $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nn$ should or shouldn't be $-1/4$ (I recalled [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%E2%88%92_2_%2B_3_%E2%88%92_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)).

I started by considering the following function series:

> $$
> f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{x^n}
> $$

by the ratio test, it can converge if $x\in\mathcal{D}:(-\infty;-1)\cup(1;+\infty)$, so it can be proved by taking the finite sum that it's pointwise convergent on $\mathcal{D}$:
$$
f_j(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{j}\frac{n}{x^n}=\frac{1}{x-1}\sum_{n=0}^{j-1}\frac{1}{x^n}-\frac{j}{x^j(x-1)}=\frac{x(x^{j}-1)}{x^j(x-1)^2}-\frac{j}{x^j(x-1)}
$$
from the above calculation it follows that $\lim_{j\to+\infty}f_j(x)=f(x)$ iff $x\in\mathcal{D}$. However, since:
$$
f(x)=x/(1-x)^2
$$
actually is defined on $x=-1$, therefore it would *seem* that $f(-1)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nn=-1/4$.

To prove the falsity of this possibilty I thought of searching the general convergence on $x=-1$: at that exact point if the distance from the finite sum and the function tends to zero as $j\to+\infty$, then the previous statement is true; if false, then the series would deviate at the limit from the function even after magnifying infinite times, and therefore will never reach $-1/4$.

It can be shown that the function is in fact uniformly convergent on entire $\mathcal{D}$:
\begin{align*}
0&=\limsup_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\x\in\mathcal{D}}}\left\lvert\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{x(x^{j}-1)}{x^j(x-1)^2}+\frac{j}{x^j(x-1)}\right\rvert\\
&=\limsup_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\x\in\mathcal{D}}}\left\lvert\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{o(x^j)}{x^j(x-1)}\right\rvert\\
&=\limsup_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\x\in\mathcal{D}}}\frac{o(x^j)}{|x|^j|x-1|}=0\hskip6cm\square
\end{align*}
but now, when the point is fixed on $x=-1$ this result is obtained (it shows neither pointwise nor uniform since UC$\implies$PC and $\neg$PC$\implies$$\neg$UC), at first PC:
$$
\lim_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\x=-1}}\frac{x(x^{j}-1)}{x^j(x-1)^2}-\frac{j}{x^j(x-1)}=\lim_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\x=-1}}\frac{1-(-1)^{j}+2j}{4(-1)^j}=\lim_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\x=-1}}\frac{j}{2(-1)^j}\to\nexists
$$
then by testing UC, as predicted above:
\begin{align*}
0&=\lim_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\k=-1}}\left\lvert-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{(-1)^{j}-1}{(-1)^j4}-\frac{j}{(-1)^j2}\right\rvert\\
&=\lim_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\k=-1}}\left\lvert\frac{-(-1)^{j}+(-1)^{j}-1}{(-1)^j4}-\frac{j}{(-1)^j2}\right\rvert\\
&=\lim_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\k=-1}}\left\lvert\frac{-1-2j}{(-1)^j4}\right\rvert\\
&=\lim_{\substack{j\to+\infty\\k=-1}}\frac{|-2j|}{4}=+\infty
\end{align*}
*(edited to show both types of divergence)*

This sums up my question: *is this method sufficient to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nn\neq-1/4$ because the distance from the function $x/(x-1)^2$ at $x=-1$ will deviate as $\infty$ from $-1/4$*?

Comment: You lost me at the definition of $f_k(x)$.

Comment: @Did It's the finite sum of the function series, an approximation, obtained by an algebraic method. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k%2Fx^k%2C+k%3D0+to+n) is the WA corresponding equation, and I think it's the same.

Comment: The series is not convergent, which should be enough to end the discussion. If you really insist on such "beasts", there is this nice book: *[Divergent Series](http://www.amazon.com/Divergent-AMS-Chelsea-Publishing-Hardy/dp/0821826492/)*, by [Godfrey Hardy](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Hardy.html). The idea is to transform the series into something convergent, with a transformation that does not affect the sum of convergent series.

Comment: Looking at $0-1+2-3+4-\cdots$ I would say that it is not defined. The series of partial sums $s_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Except that what you had written in your question was quite different from what you typed in WA. Even now, after you modified the question, things are not quite right (probably $j=k$...).

Comment: @Did Sorry, I had to change every variable (since I'm inventive... ugh). Now all the expressions [should be coherent](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%2Fx^n%2C+n%3D0+to+j+%3D+%28x%28x^j-1%29%29%2F%28x^j%28x-1%29^2%29-%28j%29%2F%28x^j%28x-1%29%29).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I know it does diverge, my question is: *is this method sufficiently strong/correct to prove it?*

Comment: Way to complicated proof for such a simple statement. Simply observing that $|s_n| = \{0,1,1,2,2,3,3,\ldots\}$ so $|s_{2n}| = |s_{2n-1}| = n \to \infty$ is enough to show divergence.

Comment: @Winther True, but the way I saw it in the beginning was to either prove false the paradoxical equation $0-1+2-3+\ldots=-1/4$.

Comment: @AndreaL. If you show that the series diverge then you have done just that! Divergence of the series implies that the statement does not make sense.

Comment: @Winther Doesn't make it in contrast with [Abel Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%E2%88%92_2_%2B_3_%E2%88%92_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)? If the latter sum method implies $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nn=-1/4$ *because of the substitution inside $f(-1)$*, and I've shown that it can't be possible; what is the right explanation then?

Comment: Ask yourself, "what do I mean when I write $0-1+2-3+\ldots$ ?" If you mean "Abel summations of it" then the statement you present is correct. However the standard interpretation is that this is to mean the limit of the sum $s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^n n$. In this way there is no ambiguity - the series diverges and thats it.

Comment: @Winther It better be divergent, I'd say. The fact that we can assign different meanings to summation tends to generate special cases as $1+2+3+\ldots=-1/12$ (noting that Ramanujan used $1-2+3-\ldots=1/4$ to construct its statement).

Comment: @AndreaL. "is this method sufficiently strong/correct to prove it?" You can't *prove* something that is wrong in the first place. All you can do is devise a process that will do no harm to convergent series, and that will hopefully make some divergent series convergent. But you may devise two such transformations that yield different values for the sum, it would be equally right. It's just a value you give conventionnally to a sum, not a proof of anything.

Comment: What Hardy's book adresses, among others, is this: what kind of divergent series can be "computed" by a given transformation? And given two transformations and a divergent series they both transform into a convergent one, is the sum the same? There are many different transformations of series for this purpose, the most well known is [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I see no flaw into your reasoning, and I may be wrong, but I took this problem as: here is the f.s. and I don't know what it does in $x=-1$, so by a process devised I concluded that it's divergent. I've always seen this procedure as a proof, because I demonstrated (with analysis) a thesis (divergence) through hypoteses.

Comment: Last, but not least: to prove that your process is actually meaningful, you have to prove it does not affect convergent series (first define it more generally to a series $\sum_n a_n$, it's not difficult). Otherwise, if it's a "one shot" method, you could as well define your sum to be $42$.

Comment: @AndreaL. Right, and a bit wrong also: you are proving something from a definition of a series that has almost nothing to do with your original series (that is divergent, as you know). You conclude something on this new series. But you have proved nothing on the former one. I guess you didn't need this whole stuff to prove $1-2+3-...$ is divergent, so what are you really trying to do? Of course analysis won't prove it's convergent, no magic here. To give it a value, you must "define" it's value to be somthind else, like with Cesaro summation.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you trying in your proof to show that $1-2+3-...$ is convergent and has value $1/4$? If so, it's doomed to fail (it *is* divergent, no matter how you prove it, and there is already a simple proof : the general term does not converge to $0$). However, if you are trying to *define* the sum to be something with some transformation process, you can read again what I wrote :-). And if so, I strongly suggest you read the aforementioned book!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I'm starting to understand. The main reason I chose this farraginous proof is to answer "NO" to your first question into your last comment *and* showing a connection on why it has been "defined" (with a similar trasnformation process, here the plugging on $f(x)$) that $-1+2-3+\ldots=-1/4$ utilizing other types of summation. Anyways, thanks for the patience `:-)` If you wish to plug in all of your comments into an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Ok, now I understand :-) Not sure about the details right now, but it seems you are playing with two limits (on $j$, and on $x$). You must be very careful with interversion of limits. Also if you have uniform convergence, this proves your series is convergent. But if you have not uniform convergence, this proves nothing: there are cases where a secondary series does not converge uniformly to what you want, yet your former series is convergent, for another reason. With positive series there is probably a way to do this, I'll have to work a bit on it ;-)